# Run Celery Worker from FLASK app

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm making an app in FLASK and I've incorporated Celery into it. However, I have to run the app via the terminal if I want the Celery worker to work as well. (`celery -A app.celery worker`). I tried running it from the main `run.py` file as follows

init.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
from celery import Celery
from kombu import serialization


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
mail = Mail(app)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT'] = ['json']
app.config['CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER'] = 'json'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER'] = 'json'
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
serialization.registry._decoders.pop("application/x-python-serialize")

from app import views
```

and run.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from app import app
# app.run(debug=True, port=9001)

from celery import current_app    
from celery.bin import worker

app = current_app._get_current_object()

worker = worker.worker(app=app)

options = {
    'broker': app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
    'loglevel': 'INFO',
    'traceback': True,
}

worker.run(**options)
```

But this gives the error `AttributeError: 'Celery' object has no attribute 'config'`

Any pointers as to what Im doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: The whole point of Celery is to run it as a separate process so that your webapp could off-load computationally intense tasks to it, so why are you trying to run Celery worker in the same process as your webapp?

Comment: basically, the command `celery -A app.celery worker` starts up both the Celery worker and the main app together. I'm looking for the python script equivalent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your run.py should be:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from app import app
# app.run(debug=True, port=9001)

from celery import current_app    
from celery.bin import worker

application = current_app._get_current_object()

worker = worker.worker(app=application)

options = {
    'broker': app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
    'loglevel': 'INFO',
    'traceback': True,
}

worker.run(**options)
```

Comment: that started up the celery worker but the main app isnt working

Comment: @Irtza.QC because the script doesn't even start the main app (`app.run` is commented)...

Comment: I did not yet test my source code. I just see you declare 'app' two times. You can refer to my example at https://github.com/thanhson1085/flask-celery-rabbitmq-generate-thumbnail to know how to work with FLASK, CELERRY, RABBITMQ